# 2 languages ​​on the website using php

Tags: php, cookies

Help please organize bi-lingual website.

So first there are two files eng.php, es.php and they will be stored in translation site.

example:

```
$lang['hi'] = 'Hi';
```

How can I organize further language choice on the site and record information about the language in cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two files like this.

Source of `en.php`:

```
$lang = array(
    'hi' => 'Hi'
);
```

Source of `es.php`:

```
$lang = array(
    'hi' => 'Hello'
);
```

And for the main content file, the source should be this way:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Make sure you initialize cookies / session
    $allowedLangs = array('en', 'es'); // Array with allowed values
    if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])) { // If already user had stored language in session
        include $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
    } elseif(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], allowedLangs)) { // If user had requested like index.php?lang=en
        include $_GET['lang'] . ".php";
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // Update the session with the language
    } else { // If user is visiting for the first time, then...
        include "en.php";
    }

    echo $lang['hi'];
?>
```

Comment: You need to validate the "allowed" $_GET['lang'] values or you risk illegal file inclusions, eg "index.php?lang=../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00"

Comment: whank you very much for your reply... if I can give the user a choice of language?

Comment: you can use pagename.php?lang=en OR pagename.php?lang=es

Comment: @mulekula yeah, you can use that. But no need of `name="es"`, not needed in this context. And whenever you use, give as `./?lang=es` instead of just `?lang=es`, sometimes it may not work!

Comment: @CyrilTourist agree with you. Sorry, I forgot about that!

Comment: when i get this URL http://werwolf.com.ua/index.php?lang=ru.php i have a truble: 
Warning: include(0) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 6

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '0' for inclusion (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 6

Comment: http://werwolf.com.ua/index.php?lang=en not working 
Warning: include(0) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 6

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '0' for inclusion (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 6
Проба Ру документ

Comment: Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 6
Hi its a English

Comment: Did you add the two files? en.php and es.php?

Comment: You get `include(0)`? Check the code once. All the files should be in the same folder. i.e., index.php, en.php and es.php. First of all, try just giving `include "en.php"` or `include "es.php"` and try.

Comment: all files in index folder with index.php...how can i get include(0)?

Comment: Let us know what is the current URL your browser has.

Comment: i write include(0) in my code and this is the result: 
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '0' for inclusion (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 14

Comment: Why did you write `include(0)`? Should I mail you the files? Its working correctly here.

Comment: very apologize, but I have another question...everything works, but when I chose a language and handed it in cookies, I do not able to switch to the previous ... what can I do to be able to change the language many times?

Comment: @mulekula we need to change the code little bit. We have given a condition to first check for the cookies and then check the `$_GET`. Just swap both. First check for the `$_GET` and then for the cookies. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
        ?>
        Choose Language...
        <a href="es.php">ES</a><a href="eng.php">ENG</a>
        <?php
    } else {
        if($_COOKIE['lang']=='es'){
            header("location:es.php");
        }
        elseif($_COOKIE['lang']=='eng'){
            header("location:eng.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

es.php // eng.php

```
<!--Your Content-->
<?php
    setcookie("lang","es/eng",time()+SECONDS_YOU_WANT)
?>
```

Comment: i have some problem Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php:6) in H:\home\werwolf.com.ua\www\index.php on line 17

Comment: write ob_start(); in top of the page 1st line

Comment: Check your code for UTF-8 BOM. [Remove UTF 8 BOM](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=utf8+bom#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=utf-8+bom+remove&oq=utf+8+bom+remo&aq=0K&aqi=g-K1g-mK1g-bK2&aql=&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l2.1641.2123.0.2872.5.5.0.0.0.0.131.520.2j3.5.0...0.0.8nSBal-hWR4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9f2a96f1279e6426&biw=1280&bih=923)

Comment: Trying to make a translation but nothing comes out.
Using the echo $lang=['hi'];