# Is there a better way to do a language stringtable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Edit: This was marked as duplicate with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913775/2-languages-on-the-website-using-php) - however, that is utilizing a cookie sesssion that the user chooses. This method is not based on cookie or user selection, but rather the developer's decision. Yes it could easily be modified to include that option for the user, but this is not the case in my question. If anything that question just confirms my method of doing this. Please reopen if topic has been closed. Thank you :)

So I am building a templated style of website, and I want to include a language stringtable, so the builder can define their language, or multiple languages..

This is what I have, and I am curious if there is better ways to do this. I haven't found much about it online, I found one thread here about setting a class to do it, but that information did not work. So this is what I came up with.

```
define(LANG,"esp");
global $lang;
$lang = array (
                    "common" => array(
                          "menu" => array("eng"=>"Menu","esp"=>"Menú"),
                          "close"  => array("eng"=>"Close","esp"=>"Cerca"),
                          "home" => array("eng"=>"Home","esp"=>"Casa"),
                    ),
                    "search" => array(
                        "submit" => array("eng"=>"Submit","esp"=>"Enviar"),
                        "notfound" => array("eng"=>"Item not found","esp"=>"Objeto no encontrado"),
                    )   
);
```

This is my function I wrote for it, as well as you can use a the array call too which I will show below

```
    function stringLang($cat,$word,$language = LANG) {
       global $lang;
       $str = $lang[$cat][$word][$language];
       return $str;     
   }
```

So it can be called by `<?php echo $lang['common']['close'][LANG]; ?>;` which will return "Cerca"

Or you can use the function to call `<?php echo stringLang('common','home'); ?>` which will return "Casa"

My question is, is this an okay method to this? What are better methods without using a bunch of defines? Thanks!

Comment: `gettext()` : http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php - though it has some *issues* it's arguably the fastest/best way to get multi-lingual content into a templated PHP website. You'll also need something like poedit : https://poedit.net/